# Various CSS questions to customize theme

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to programming and trying to customize a theme that I am using. However I am having several issues where if I fix one thing something else breaks. I've researched solutions for about 3 days and I think it's time I reach out to some more experienced with CSS for help.

I tried setting up a JSFiddle but it's not working correctly as I can't access the HTML file directly. The website is [www.preethijagadeesh.com](http://preethijagadeesh.com/). Would it be possible to review the html/css files and provide suggestions for the following requirements?

1. Center the title (I believe this is found in the 'site_header'
   class which is pasted below). I am using margin to change the percentage and it looks
   different on various browsers.
2. I would also like to 'fix' the title so that when I scroll the title
   goes with me. I used 'position: fixed' but it cause all the
       content in the 'index' ID (pasted below) to overlay on the title/site_header.
   The text in the 'About' page appears to be more on the left with
   a lot of white space on the right. No matter what I am unable to get
   the content to center regardless of which class I update.
3. The line/border_bottom that appears under the navigation items should be 
   the same length as the text. I tried updating it but now every time
   I hover over the items the text/options move around
4. overlay a
       black color on the thumbnails on hover. I got it to 'kind of' work.
       It's just when I hover on the thumbnails, the images and the
       'background color' flicker
5. Widen the gap between the thumbnails.
   Right now, there are two columns, it would be great to just put some
   space in between them.

Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Comment: We can't see any of the content that you're referring to in the "about" and "contact" pages in the JSFiddle. Is this website hosted online so we can look at it?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the JSFiddle link and made the website public - http://preethijagadeesh.com/ is the url. Please let me know if you need any further info.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change

`.header_image {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 80px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }`

to

```
.header_image {
    text-align: center
    margin-top: 80px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

2. Add these to .site_header:

`.site_header{
        /* old css remains here... */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0; 
}`

3. Move the padding properties from the a to their parent instead (the .page_link div).
4. and 5. I can't get the thumbnails to display on your jsfiddle so I can't really give the answer. But for 4 I think something like this will help:
   put a `<div class="thumbnail-overlay"></div>` inside your thumbnail html.
   For the css:

   ```
   .thumbnail-overlay{
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       z-index: 1; 
       /* this z-index should be higher than the thumbnails' child element. If no z-index is set for their child element leave it at 1 */
   }

   .thumbnail-overlay:hover{
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help!

Item 1 - Worked perfectly!

Item 2 -  I used your recommendations but the thumbnails now appear over the titles and clear: both or clear: top doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Item 3 - Worked perfectly

Item 4 & 5: I can't access the HTML file as I am using a theme and updating the CSS to my liking. The actual website may be accessed at www.preethijagadeesh.com - 

Would you have any further suggestions for Items 2, 4 and 5? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

1. `.header_image` is floating, so you can't center it nicely. If you remove the float and then use `text-align: center;`, the image should center.
2. Not really sure where you are wanting the title to appear - should it be above the content or to the left of the content?
3. You have removed the `padding` from the links to resize the underline, but it's only been changed on hover. This is what is causing the "jumping" navigation links. If you add this code to `.navigation a` (instead of `.navigation a:hover`), this should work nicely:

   .navigation a {
       padding: 0;
       margin-right: 6px;
       margin-left: 7px;
   }
4. Instead of using `.thumb_image:hover`, try using `.thumbnail:hover .thumb_image` and see if that's helps with the flickering. Also, maybe remove the `background-position: 0 -30px;`.
5. Is a plugin being used to generate and control the thumbnail images? The absolute positioning being used on the thumbnail images will make it difficult to reposition them.

Comment: This was super helpful! Thanks! Your assistance worked perfectly for Items 1 and 3. 

For Item 4, I tried your suggestions however they caused the thumbnail to disappear on hover (including the background color) would you have any other suggestions? 

Item 5: I do believe there may be a plugin being used, any suggestions would be very greatly appreciated though! 

Thanks again so much!

Comment: Can you find out what plugin is being used for the images?

Comment: if you change `.thumb_image:hover {` to `.thumbnail:hover .thumb_image {`, the hover effect should work OK.

Answer (score -1):

You should be creating the site offline and reviewing your work before migrating the site to your host.

If your host does not allow you to migrate your site and/or denies you access to your HTML files, you need find a new web host.